# Remove the property in page for inno setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascal

```
Page.add('Example');
```

This will add the value to the respective page and can be retrieved using

```
Page.Values[0];
```

What is the syntax to remove /delete the value which is added?
Also is there any way to check if the "Page.Values" has any values or how to find the size?

Thanks in advance,
DeeJay

Comment: There is no method for this (even the underlying collections are not directly accessible, so no luck here).

Comment: Can I check the size or check if it has any values at all?

Comment: No, even that is not possible. Only the `Add` method returns the actual count of items. You will need to remember the item count by yourself. Or build the page when you know all the details (if your question raised because of that).

Comment: My requirement is I provide the SQL Server selection via radio buttons in page1 and based on the option selected it allows me to browse the setup file in page2. Now, if I click on "back" and select a different SQL Server option, page2 has two browse setup file options. That is why I was looking to remove the value. Any workaround if possible?? Thanks!!

Comment: If we are talking about a `TInputFileWizardPage`, then you can e.g. hide the UI controls for the items you want to hide (e.g. for `TInputDirWizardPage` that would be problem because the fields cannot remain empty if I remember that right). Also, if you hide some item's controls, you might need to shift the controls of the next item (if there's any). In such case would be probably easier to create a custom page.

Comment: Thanks for the input again :) :). U saved me a lot of time. Thanks a lot.